# Select date range via inputtype date

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to select a daterange by using two datepickers (input type date) where the min and max is set by the 1st or 2nd datepicker. I know it's possible in jQuery but I prefer to use the input type date. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Two inputs, one for min and other for max:

```
 <form>
  <div>
    <label for="partyMin">Choose since date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="partyMin" name="minDate">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="partyMax">Choose until date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="partyMax" name="maxDate" >
  </div>
 </form>
```